# Namespaces do not work after allowing server to parse php in html files

Tags: php, .htaccess, namespaces

I have put the following in the my server's .htaccess file:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .htm .html
```

I am using GoDaddy hosting.

After doing this, I get a parse error at a line like this:

```
namespace {
```

The error is: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'`

When doing this: `namespace Name {`, I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`

By the way, the namespace usage is from a third-party library, not in my own code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @raina77ow I'm on version 5.4 and I'm certain it supports namespaces because it used to work before I modified .htaccess.

Comment: Are you 2000% sure that the PHP version being used is 5.4?

Comment: Argh, now I'm a bit confused. See, though I consider my answer helpful for the question as described by the title (how to use namespaces in HTML files), if it were the problem, you wouldn't had seen the error message you quoted; that one is caused by the old version of PHP (which parser just doesn't know anything about `namespace` word). Would you mind rechecking it?

Comment: @raina77ow I'm certain that the version is 5.4. Also, the namespace code is, in fact, in a .php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though everything said below might be helpful and applicable in your case, it seems that the problem has been introduced with than line in your .htaccess file:

`AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .htm .html`

... which set the older version of PHP as a handler of requests. Replace it with...

`AddHandler x-httpd-php5-4 .php .htm .html`

---

Move the namespace declaration at the top of your HTML file. Quoting [**the docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php):

> The only code construct allowed before a namespace declaration is the
>   `declare` statement, for defining encoding of a source file. In
>   addition, no non-PHP code may precede a namespace declaration,
>   including extra whitespace.

```
<html> 
<?php namespace MyProject; // fatal error 
                           // namespace must be the first statement in the script 
?>
```

Note that you can put HTML stuff in-between different namespaces (it's just the first statement that should be at the top), when used like this:

```
<?php
   namespace One;
   function foo(){}
?>
<p>Got some <?= __NAMESPACE__ ?> for ya!</p>
<?php
   namespace Two;
   function foo(){}
?>
```

(it's easy to see that technically `<p>` belongs to the first namespace, but that hardly matters).

Comment: What if there are multiple namespaces in the same php file?

Comment: I'm still getting an error. The top of my file is now: `<?php namespace {`

Comment: Like I mentioned, this is not my own code. This is the password_compat library: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat It also doesn't work even if I give it a name.

Comment: What is the use of the namespace declarations followed by a semicolon?

Comment: After changing the line in .htaccess like you suggested, every file on the server is now prompted to download when accessed.

Comment: sadly, the same happens.

Comment: What about now? With '5-4' at the end, hyphen instead of a dot. Make sure you restart Apache.